# comparing a string to multiple array in c

Tags: c, linux, string

End game was to compare the extensions of files in the directory to 2 separate string of arrays to that i could sort it and put it 2 different folders..

I am having a problem comparing the strings of two different arrays.. esp with 2 different sized string arrays..

any suggestions is appreciated..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
 DIR *dirP;
 struct dirent *dp;
 char *fileN; int i = 0;
 char *extMov[]= {".mp4",".flv"};
 char *extMusic[]= {".mp3"};

 dirP = opendir ("/Users/abc/Downloads");
 if (dirP != NULL)
 {
  while ((dp = readdir(dirP)) != NULL)
  {
   if((fileN = strrchr(dp->d_name,'.')) != NULL)
   {
    for (i=0; extMov[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
     if(strcmp (fileN,extMov[i]) == 0)
     {
      printf("%s\n",dp->d_name);
     }
    }
   }
  }
  closedir(dirP);
 }
 else
  perror (" Could not open the directory\n");
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem you have is that arrays are not normally terminated in any way. So in your loop

```
for (i=0; extMov[i] != NULL; i++)
```

you will most likely step out of bounds, and continue iterating untill there is a `NULL` somewhere in memory, which might be quite far out of bounds. Accessing an array out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and makes your whole program suspect of errors and illegalities, even though it might compile fine and without warnings.

---

To solve this problem you can use a little trick to calculate the number entries in an array:

```
for (i=0; i < sizeof(extMov) / sizeof(extMov[0]); i++)
```

Do note however that this trick only works on proper arrays. You have to remember that arrays often decays to pointer, for example when passing an array as argument to a function, and then this trick will not work.

Comment: this idea definitely works.. but is there a way to compare 2 arrays in this case , extMov and extMusic in a single pass(of for loop)? the problem i face is both arrays will be of different so i will need 2 for loops to do the job...

Comment: If the size of the array are not the same yes using two for loops will be the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

your `for loop` is looking for a NULL value to stop, but you didn't set a NULL value to your array.
So this `extMov[i] != NULL` might never be found (depending on the content of your memory)

```
char *extMov[]= {".mp4",".flv", NULL};
```

I explicitly add a NULL as the last entry of my array to be sure to have it.